# Problem saving CNN

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, cnn

I have built a CNN and I want to save it. I am using Google Colab,

```
import os
datadir = '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks'
models_dir = datadir + '/models/'

def savemodel(model,problem):
    filename = os.path.join(models_dir, '%s.h5' %problem)
    model.save(filename)
    print("\nModel saved successfully on file %s\n" %filename)

# Save the model
savemodel(model,'saved_model')
```

where `model = Sequential()`. But when I try to do this I have the error:

```
    OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-20-6d0193f1e7f1> in <module>()
     11 
     12 # Save the model
---> 13 savemodel(model,'saved_model')

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py in make_fid(name, 
mode, userblock_size, fapl, fcpl, swmr)
    146         fid = h5f.create(name, h5f.ACC_EXCL, fapl=fapl, fcpl=fcpl)
    147     elif mode == 'w':
--> 148         fid = h5f.create(name, h5f.ACC_TRUNC, fapl=fapl, fcpl=fcpl)
    149     elif mode == 'a':
    150         # Open in append mode (read/write).

h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

h5py/h5f.pyx in h5py.h5f.create()

OSError: Unable to create file (unable to open file: name = 
'/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/models/saved_model.h5', errno = 2, 
error message = 'No such file or directory', flags = 13, o_flags = 242)
```

Can somebody help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the target directory `/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/models/` exist?

Comment: Guess your path is the problem, check if the target dir exists. Maybe include something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273192/how-can-i-safely-create-a-nested-directory